# Haskell from integer into a string (own function)

Tags: haskell

I need help with my function to convert an integer into a string:

for example: fromInteger 19 == "91"

My auxiliary-function to convert an integer into a character:

```
fromDigit :: Integer -> Char
fromDigit 0 = '0'
fromDigit 1 = '1'
fromDigit 2 = '2'
fromDigit 3 = '3'
fromDigit 4 = '4'
fromDigit 5 = '5' 
fromDigit 6 = '6'
fromDigit 7 = '7'
fromDigit 8 = '8'
fromDigit 9 = '9'
```

This is my main function:

```
fromInteger :: Integer -> String
fromInteger n = 
if n == 0 then ""
else fromInteger(tail n) ++ fromDigit(head n)
```

I should only use: tail, head, :, null and mathematical functions

Comment: "I need help" - what help? Writing the code for you? It's an assignment you have to figure out, what else would you ask the community to help with?

Comment: An integer is not a list, so you cannot use `head` and `tail`. You probably should be dividing by powers of ten instead.

Comment: You might consider using function [divMod](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=divMod&scope=set%3Astackage).

Comment: is this possible without split the number?

Comment: @MaxMustermann It is quite straightforward using `fromInteger` or `show`, but you already said you do not want to use these funcitons.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, integers are not lists, so you cannot pass inteers to `head` or `tail`. Then `fromInteger` is already defined in the prelude, so I'd recommend renaming it to `fromInteger_`. So to extract the least significant digit, you can reduce the integer modulo 10. But to apply the recusion you also need the leading digits which you can get by using an integer division by 10. There is a nice function `divMod` that does both in one step. Now your suggested function cannot work as you define it to return a `String` but the first case does not return a string, so let's change that to a empty string `""`. Then you want to use `++` to concatenate strings. This means we need to conver the digit we get from `fromDigit` to a string - and we can do that by enclosing it in a brackets. (Strings are nothing but lists of characters.) With these modification everything seems to work fine:

```hs
fromInteger_ :: Integer -> String
fromInteger_ n 
 | n == 0 = ""
 | otherwise = fromInteger_ d ++ [fromDigit m]
   where (d, m) = divMod n 10

main = print $ fromInteger_ 12451
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc@9CsIwFAXgPU9xEKGKCk1taxXqoouDk6OIFBrbYH8kBl1895orgrcugXw5OZdbZverqqquu5i23upCW6xW2DVWFcpgtsamzIz4PfpI4fkeE0kiuQQkAZc5yZxLSBJyiUgiD4xiopiHFiQLLglJwmVJsvTEh76bnP@2Olijm6KfaCDwcmeafrYcDOja2lKZp74rJ710jskEx9/U@iQAPF1aYZRPUY/dj1w/9m3uOqUvRJ1pV46bm2wx7LfJIIxk170B)

I don't see though how `head` and `tail` or `null` would help you with your approach.

Comment: 123451 should be printed as: "154321" and not "123451"

Comment: Oh I see, I assumed that was a typo in your question. In that case you need to flip the order of the arguments of `++`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a simple function to get the digits in a list (in reverse order), using `mod` and `div` - or simply `divMod`

```hs
revDigs :: Integral a => a -> [a]
revDigs 0 = []
revDigs num = currDig : revDigs restDigs
    where (restDigs, currDig) = num `divMod` 10
```

Now all you have to do, is map over your own `fromDigit` function on the result of `revDigs`.

Do note that there's a library function for this already - [`intToDigit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:intToDigit). But I assume you cannot use that here.

So the final result would look like-

```hs
fromIntNum :: Integer -> [Char]
fromIntNum = map fromDigit . revDigs
```