# Element of an infinite list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am writing a character encoder in haskell. For my assessement i am not allowed to use any built in functions such as `elem`, etc
One of my functions is called int_to_char, which converts an integer to a character
I am thinking of using an infinite lists, one of [`1`,`2`..] infinite list of sequential character numbers
So my questions are can you do an infinite character list?
Can you find the element of an infinte list?
And which is probably a yes, is there a much simpler way to do this with no built in functions!

EDIT: The code i have updated is for character encoding which goes up to 9 characters maximum, however, i am trying to make an encoder for characters longer than 9 so for example aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb etc. I am not looking for a solution, just an explanation on what the best approach would be

```
int_to_char :: Integer -> Char
int_to_char 0 = '0'
int_to_char 1 = '1'
int_to_char 2 = '2'
int_to_char 3 = '3'
int_to_char 4 = '4'
int_to_char 5 = '5'
int_to_char 6 = '6'
int_to_char 7 = '7'
int_to_char 8 = '8'
int_to_char 9 = '9'
int_to_char x = error "Number must be between 0 and 9"

length_char :: Char -> String -> Integer
length_char c [] = 0
length_char c (x:xs)
    | (c == x ) = 1 + length_char c xs
    | otherwise = 0 + length_char c []

drop_char :: Char -> String -> String
drop_char c [] = []
drop_char c (x:xs)
    | (c == x)  = drop_char c xs
    | otherwise = (x:xs) ++ drop_char c []  


encode :: String -> String
encode [] = []
encode (x:xs) = x : (int_to_char(length_char x (x:xs))) : encode 
(drop_char x xs)
```

Comment: If you could provide more information than "converts an integer to a character" (such as *how* exactly the integers map to characters) you might get some useful tips.

Comment: Recent prior art here [SO-q64766808](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766808)  ?

Comment: There are only a finite number of Unicode code points, so there's no need for an infinite list. There are infinitely many integers (though only a finitely  number of `Int` values), but only finitely many integers would be mapped to a Unicode code point.

Answer (score 2):

> can you do an infinite character list?

The answer to the question as asked is yes, and here's a simple example:

```
infinitelyManyAs :: [Char]
infinitelyManyAs = 'A' : infinitelyManyAs
```

But I suspect the *intention* of the question was to get a *finite* character list of all the characters in some order. Here's some hints:

- You can use the same list enumeration syntax you used for numbers, but with characters in place of the numbers. For example, `['a','b'..]` is a list of `Char`acters.
- `Char` is an instance of `Bounded`, so there is `minBound` and `maxBound` for the smallest and largest characters, respectively. But perhaps this counts as a "built in 'function'" and can't be used, I don't know.
- Besides the usual character literal format, there are numeric character literal formats; for example, `'a'`, `'\97'`, `'\x61'`, and `'\o141'` all represent the same character.

> Can you find the element of an infinite list?

Yes, there are many ways. For the purposes of practicing Haskell, I recommend writing a recursive function that traverses the infinite list, though an experienced Haskeller would likely prefer creating (or reusing) some basic list-processing functions first and then chaining them together. (List comprehensions would be considered and discarded because they can't report failure for infinite lists in a sane way.)

Comment: I have updated my code, does this help? Just looking for the best way to do this.